Blazor WASM (.NET 6) - Ways to Improve de/serialization performance
It's a known issue that de/serialization in Blazor WASM is pretty slow.
This benchmark shows that serialization in the Mono interpreter is about ~35-90x slower than .NET Core, of course this was around the time of .NET 5 and numerous improvements have been made since then and performance seems to be much better in .NET 8 but its ultimately still much slower than .NET Core.
This is specially bad when you consider that Blazor WASM has no multithreading, and the deserialization call is thread-blocking, causing UI to visually freeze when deserializing a large quantity of objects.
So what I'd like to ask is:

Is there ANY way to do the de/serialization in a non-thread blocking way?

I've thought about using web workers but it probably wouldn't work since there would still be need of de/serializing between the application and the web worker.

In what ways could I improve de/serialization performance when dealing with a large quantity of objects?

Keep in mind that I'm stuck with .NET 6.

How much data are you working with?

More than I should be. I already know that one solution is changing my app's logic in order to reduce the amount of objects I have to deserialize, and that's probably what I'm gonna end up doing, but I'd still like to know about improving serialization performance nonetheless.

It was a genuine question

I feel like this is a question being worth an answer, although migrating to .NET 8 and eventually 9 would definitely help you, and .NET 6 will be EOS in 3 months. I feel like it is still something people will have to figure out when transitioning desktop apps to Blazor apps.

@MisterMagoo About 100k~600k records which have about 5~7 columns of simple string/int values

How many MB of data is that? Are you using source generated JSON serializers? Are you using AOT compilation

There's not a lot you can do to beyond reducing the amount of data - processing smaller chunks, using source generated JSON serializers and AOT compilation though. You are stuck on dotnet 6 - so you should let whoever is keeping you stuck on it know that dotnet 8 would help - in my testing, blazor on dotnet 6 is about 5 times slower to de-serialize json than blazor on dotnet 8 (wasm)

@MisterMagoo AOT might help, but it takes so long to build...
I wasn't aware of source-generation, will also give it a shot, Thank you for your insights.
